# Rails 3. Getting multiple things from different tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an API in Ruby on Rails 3 and in this API I got users and users can be friends. This is handled through Contacts. When a user "asks" for all his or her contacts I create an array that takes the Ids of each user and get the User object for them so that I can get the real name of the contact and not just the contact ID.

This works fine, but I also need the ID of the contact so that I can for example delete contacts in the iPhone app that I am developing. How can I do this? How can the below code be modify to get the contact ID for each user and the user object?

http://pastie.org/1847350

**UPDATE**

The current JSON output is pastie.org/1848590.
I want the contact IDs to be a sub array of the main User object array. Like the latest message is now.

Thankful for all input!

Comment: Can you put your Models.

Comment: This is the Contact model: http://pastie.org/1847692. This is the User model: http://pastie.org/1847695.

Comment: And what do you want at the end? ex: array[user.id, contact1.id, contact2.id ...]

Comment: The current output is like this: http://pastie.org/1848590. I want the contact ID to be sub array like the latest message is now. How can I do this?

Comment: Put me a exemple of output you want not the current

Comment: I want it to look like this: http://pastie.org/1848845. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use the same technique as your last_message method ?

Comment: Because then I do not know how to pass a parameter to those methods.

Comment: def contact_data self.contacts.first end is not what you want ? I not see what you want to mean, with your output, and what is the purpose of contact (and not just User has_many :contacts, :class => User)

Answer (score 1):

Contact is also the user, I think you just need to create a user model and add a self association with class_name: "contact" and this relation will b the one to many relationship  one user has_many contacts.

```
 has_many :contacts, class: "contacts", foreign_key: "contact_id"
```

Here is cast for this

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association
```

after the association you just need to find that user and then just

```
@users.collect{|user| user.contacts }
```

returns you the list of the contacts I think that might help you.

Cheers